# C26495 Variable Specific

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Is there a way to disable the VS's C26495 warning (Always initialize a member variable) for specific variables? Some member variables should not be initialized in the constructor. Examples include those in MFC's InitInstance and OnNewDocument.

#pragma warning disable C26495 and #pragma warning restore C26495 surrounding the variables in the class declaration or around the constructor didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Adding the `#pragma warning(disable:26495)` before the c'tor and then `#pragma warning(default:26495)` immediately after it should work (it does, for me, in a test case). Another option is  adding the `[[gsl::suppress(type.5)]]` attribute to the c'tor. The pragma 'code' you have shown looks wrong - is that *exactly* what you tried?

Comment: ... but note, both options will suppress the warning for **all** uninitialized variables, not just specific ones.

Comment: *"Some member variables should not be initialized in the constructor."* - That is, unequivocally, wrong. **All** member variables **must** be initialized in the c'tor. They may not be initialized to their final values, but you certainly wouldn't want an uninitialized pointer wreak havoc upon your heap.

Comment: Yeah. Following up on what @IInspectable said: Can you give an example of a member of your `CWinApp`-derived class, where initializing (even to an unusable value) in the c'tor would be harmful or wrong? That value would, of course, need to be overwritten in the `InitInstance` method, but it should still have a 'base' default value given to it by the c'tor.

Comment: Yep, typed the pragma wrong. Surprised the compiler didn't catch it. That'll work. Thank you.

Comment: If you wish to silence the compiler, warning you about your running straight into UB, at least do it properly: `#pragma warning(push)` `#pragma warning(disable : whatever)` ... `#pragma warning(pop)`. Not initializing member variables in the c'tor is **instant** UB.

Comment: *"typed the pragma wrong. Surprised the compiler didn't catch it"* - MSVC will warn about unknown pragmas, unknown pragma warning types, or non-numeric pragma warning list items. You either didn't look carefully enough at the compiler output, or disabled those warnings as well.

Comment: This is my reasoning. In an SDI application the document is reused. That means the constructor is only called once. On subsequent calls, anything you did in the constructor is gone, overwritten by the previous document. It is, in effect, uninitialized data. Initialization must occur in OnNewDocument (or DeleteContents). I'm guessing something similar happens in InitInstance (constructor called in only the first instance?). Otherwise, why would exist?

Comment: How do you plan to implement `DeleteContents` that is well defined while accessing uninitialized class members? How do you plan to write a `CDocument` d'tor that is well defined while accessing uninitialized class members? Your only options here are to either leak resources, or fixing the compiler warnings instead. The latter seems like the more rational way forward.

Comment: How do you leak resources in your document if you are using smart pointers? In CWinApp you would need to use raw pointers initialized in InitInstance and cleaned up in ExitInstance. You can't rely on anything you initialized in your constructor.